# FTP issue with iptables

Tags: linux, ftp, iptables, centos7

I have a problem with connecting through FTP when iptables is enabled. I've tried all suggestions from [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10400672/linux-bash-setting-iptables-rules-to-allow-both-active-and-passive-ftp) and a few others, but I'm still getting:

```
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

There's no problem with connection when I turn off iptables, so I'm sure this is what's causing the issue.

This is how my iptables file looks like:

```
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 2020 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
# Allow FTP connections @ port 21
-A INPUT  -p tcp --sport 21 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 21 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the order of the rules is important. Since you have specified the `REJECT` rule before the `FTP ACCEPT` rules, `FTP` packets are rejected by that rule before reaching the relevant rules and having any chance of getting accepted.

Secondly, [the link you've mentioned in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26659223/3903832) discusses the rules required by the server, and not by the client. The appropriate rules for the client are opposite.

Since the default policy of the `OUTPUT` chain is `ACCEPT`, and you have allowed packets of `ESTABLISHED` or `RELATED` connections into your machine, `passive-mode FTP` should already be supported by your rule set.

In order to support `active-mode FTP` as well, you need to allow incoming `TCP` connections originating from the server at port `20`, as follows:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 20 -j ACCEPT
```

[This link](http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html) supplies a concise summary of the rationale for the above rules.

---

Since in `active-mode FTP` the data connection's hosts and ports can be reliably and easily determined from the control connection's hosts and ports, I think that loading the `nf_conntrack_ftp` module would prove the ad-hoc rule for allowing incoming `TCP` connections originating from the server at port `20` redundant. I haven't checked this, but loading the module with `modprobe nf_conntrack_ftp` might suffice because incoming `RELATED` and `ESTABLISHED` traffic is allowed. This approach would be preferable since it's a bit more secure.

Answer (score 0):

The rule should be as given below:

---

```
$IPT -A INPUT  -p tcp --dport 21 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

$IPT -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 21 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

---

The INPUT chain should have destination port 21 opened for incoming connections. Let me know your feedback after trying this out.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help.

Comment: @Nicolas . How about manually running the command in terminal rather than editing the file directly?